# Issues writing a query that would fetch the second degree friends of Abiodun considering the pattern and the relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

As a newbie, I am trying to write a cypher query that would fetch the second-degree friends of Abiodun(node) considering the pattern and the relationships.

*Initial codes*

```
1) CREATE (abiodun:Person {name:"Abiodun"})
   RETURN abiodun

2) MATCH (abiodun:Person {name:"Abiodun"})
   CREATE (abiodun)-[like:LIKE]->(neo:Database {name:"Neo4j" }) 
   RETURN abiodun,like,neo

3)MATCH (abiodun:Person {name:"Abiodun"})
  FOREACH (name in ["Rajesh","Anna","Julia","Andrew"] |
  CREATE (abiodun)-[:FRIEND]->(:Person {name:name}))

4)MATCH (neo:Database {name:"Neo4j"})
  MATCH (anna:Person {name:"Anna"})
  CREATE (anna)-[:FRIEND]->(:Person:Expert {name:"Amanda"})-[:WORKED_WITH]->(neo) here
```

*Actual issue(what i did so far*

```
MATCH (abiodun) WHERE not ((abiodun)-[:FRIEND]->(myFriends)) 
RETURN n
```

[image]

I am trying to write a query that will display only Amanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a fixed length relationship from Abiodun to Amanda.
The meaning of "*2" in the relationship is "give me a friend of friend of Abiodun".

```
MATCH (:Person {name: "Abiodun"}) - [:FRIEND*2] -> (p:Person)
RETURN p
```

This is found in details here: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#varlength-rels

Comment: I posted a question on Neo4j recently.. Please can you help look into it? thanks